# Is the following derivation for the Normal Equation correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\displaystyle J(\theta):=\frac{1}{2}(X \theta-\vec{y})^{T}(X \theta-\vec{y})$.

I wish to solve the normal equations that is to say finding partial derivative of $J$ with respect to $\theta$ and setting it equal to $0$. I proceed as follow:

\begin{align*}
\nabla_{\theta}J(\theta)&=\nabla_{\theta} \frac{1}{2}(X \theta-\vec{y})^{T}(X \theta-\vec{y}) \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \nabla_{\theta}\left((X \theta)^{T} X \theta-(X \theta)^{T} \vec{y}-\vec{y}^{T}(X \theta)+\vec{y}^{T} \vec{y}\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \nabla_{\theta}\left(\theta^{T}\left(X^{T} X\right) \theta-\vec{y}^{T}(X \theta)-\vec{y}^{T}(X \theta)\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \nabla_{\theta}\left(\theta^{T}\left(X^{T} X\right) \theta-2\left(X^{T} \vec{y}\right)^{T} \theta\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(2 X^{T} X \theta-2 X^{T} \vec{y}\right) \\
&=X^{T} X \theta-X^{T} \vec{y}
\end{align*}
So this means $\theta=\left(X^{T} X\right)^{-1} X^{T} y$

Is this derivation correct or is there any missing step?

Note that:

1. $\theta$ is an $(n+1)\times1$ column vector.
2. $y$ is an $m\times1$ column vector.
3. $X$ is an $\mathbb{R^{m\times(n+1)}}$ matrix.

Comment: What are $X, \theta$ and $y$ ?

Comment: This is correct

Comment: So $X$ is an $m\times(n+1)$ matrix called the design matrix. $\theta$ is an $n\times1$ column vector. $y$ is also an $n\times 1$ column vector. These parameters are based on the derivation of the normal equations to solve linear regression.

Comment: How can you multiply an $m\times (n+1)$ matrix by an $n\times 1$ vector?

Comment: It is still wrong because in that case $X \theta$ has size $m\times 1$ and you cannot take the difference with $y$.

Comment: You are correct, $y$ is thus an $m\times 1$ vector

Comment: @Gribouillis, OP is talking about least squares regression setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivation is correct. You could also use the definition
\begin{equation}
h^T\nabla_\theta F(\theta) = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{t}(F(\theta + t h) - F(\theta))
\end{equation}
for all $h\in {\mathbb R}^{n+1}$
Applying this with $F(\theta) = J(\theta)$ gives
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rcl}
\frac{1}{t}(J(\theta + t h) - J(\theta)) &=& \frac{1}{2}(X h)^T (X\theta - y) + \frac{1}{2}(X\theta - y)^T (X h) + O(t)\\
&=&h^T X^T (X\theta -y) + O(t)\\
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you very much!